# Use swift Codable to decode JSON with values as keys

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a problem decoding a JSON structure which I cannot change to make it easier to decode (it's coming from firebase)..

How do I decode the following JSON into objects?
The problem is how to convert "7E7-M001". It's the name of a container which has drawers. The drawers name is also used as a key.

```
{
  "7E7-M001" : {
    "Drawer1" : {
      "101" : {
        "Partnumber" : "F101"
      },
      "102" : {
        "Partnumber" : "F121"
      }
    }
  },
  "7E7-M002": {
    "Drawer1": {
      "201": {
        "Partnumber": "F201"
      },
      "202": {
        "Partnumber": "F221"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What do I have to fix in the Container & Drawer class to have the key as a title property and an array of objects in these classes ?

```
class Container: Codable {
    var title: String
    var drawers: [Drawer]
}

class Drawer: Codable {
    var title: String
    var tools: [Tool]
}

class Tool: Codable {
    var title: String
    var partNumber: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case partNumber = "Partnumber"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First I'm going to make some slight simplifications so I can focus on the important points of this question. I'm going to make everything immutable, replace the classes with structs, and only implement Decodable. Making this Encodable is a separate issue.

The central tool for handling unknown value keys is a CodingKey that can handle any string:

```
struct TitleKey: CodingKey {
    let stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}
```

The second important tool is the ability to know your own title. That means asking the decoder "where are we?" That's the last element in the current coding path.

```
extension Decoder {
    func currentTitle() throws -> String {
        guard let titleKey = codingPath.last as? TitleKey else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: codingPath,
                                                    debugDescription: "Not in titled container"))
        }
        return titleKey.stringValue
    }
}
```

And then we need a way to decode elements that are "titled" this way:

```
extension Decoder {
    func decodeTitledElements<Element: Decodable>(_ type: Element.Type) throws -> [Element] {
        let titles = try container(keyedBy: TitleKey.self)
        return try titles.allKeys.map { title in
            return try titles.decode(Element.self, forKey: title)
        }
    }
}
```

With that, we can invent a protocol for these "titled" things and decode them:

```
protocol TitleDecodable: Decodable {
    associatedtype Element: Decodable
    init(title: String, elements: [Element])
}

extension TitleDecodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init(title: try decoder.currentTitle(),
                  elements: try decoder.decodeTitledElements(Element.self))
    }
}
```

And that's most of the work. We can use this protocol to make decoding pretty easy for the upper-level layers. Just implement `init(title:elements:)`.

```
struct Drawer: TitleDecodable {
    let title: String
    let tools: [Tool]
    init(title: String, elements: [Tool]) {
        self.title = title
        self.tools = elements
    }
}

struct Container: TitleDecodable {
    let title: String
    let drawers: [Drawer]

    init(title: String, elements: [Drawer]) {
        self.title = title
        self.drawers = elements
    }
}
```

`Tool` is a little different since it's a leaf node and has other things to decode.

```
struct Tool: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let partNumber: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case partNumber = "Partnumber"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.title = try decoder.currentTitle()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.partNumber = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .partNumber)
    }
}
```

That just leaves the very top level. We'll create a `Containers` type just to wrap things up.

```
struct Containers: Decodable {
    let containers: [Container]
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.containers = try decoder.decodeTitledElements(Container.self)
    }
}
```

And to use it, decode the top level `Containers`:

```
let containers = try JSONDecoder().decode(Containers.self, from: json)
print(containers.containers)
```

Note that since JSON objects are not order-preserving, the arrays may not be in the same order as the JSON, and may not be in the same order between runs.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/eb3b8628ef5e8a15f3794fa70ae96f3a)

Comment: Incredible answer

Comment: [See below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311890/4704319) I have extend Rob's answer to give a more general answer and to give it more capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to extend Rob's answer to give a more general answer and to give it more capabilities. First we'll take an example Json and identify all the scenarios that can be contained within.

```
let json = Data("""
{
    "id": "123456",            // id -> primitive data type that can be decoded normally
    "name": "Example Name",    // name -> primitive data type that can be decoded 
    "address": {               // address -> key => static, object => has static key-value pairs
        "city": "Negombo",
        "country": "Sri Lanka"
    },
    "email": {                 // email -> key => static, object => has only one key-value pair which has a dynamic key. When you're sure, user can have only one email.
        "example@gmail.com": { // example@gmail.com -> key => dynamic key, object => in this example the object is 
                               // normal decodable object. But you can have objects that has dynamic key-value pairs.
            "verified": true
        }
    },
    "phone_numbers": {         // phone_numbers -> key => static, object => has multiple key-value pairs which has a dynamic keys. Assume user can have multiple phone numbers.
        "+94772222222": {      // +94772222222 -> key => dynamic key, object => in this example the object is 
                               // normal decodable object. But you can have objects that has dynamic key-value pairs.
            "isActive": true
        },
        "+94772222223": {      // +94772222223 -> key => another dynamic key, object => another object mapped to dynamic key +94772222223
            "isActive": false
        }
    }
}
""".utf8)
```

At the end you will be able to read all the values as follows,

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let userObject = try decoder.decode(UserModel.self, from: json)

    print("User ID             : \(String(describing: userObject.id))")
    print("User Name           : \(String(describing: userObject.name))")
    print("User Address city   : \(String(describing: userObject.address?.city))")
    print("User Address country: \(String(describing: userObject.address?.country))")
    print("User Email.         : \(String(describing: userObject.email?.emailContent?.emailAddress))")
    print("User Email Verified : \(String(describing: userObject.email?.emailContent?.verified))")
    print("User Phone Number 1 : \(String(describing: userObject.phoneNumberDetails?.phoneNumbers.first?.number))")
    print("User Phone Number 2 : \(String(describing: userObject.phoneNumberDetails?.phoneNumbers[1].number))")
    print("User Phone Number 1 is Active : \(String(describing: userObject.phoneNumberDetails?.phoneNumbers.first?.isActive))")
    print("User Phone Number 2 is Active : \(String(describing: userObject.phoneNumberDetails?.phoneNumbers[1].isActive))")
} catch {
    print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
}
```

So up to address key, you can easily Decode. But after that you're gonna need a specific Object structure to hold all the data mapped by dynamic key-value pairs.
So here is my suggested Swift Object structure. Assume the above Json is for UserModel.

```
import Foundation

struct UserModel: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let address: Address?
    let email: Email?
    let phoneNumberDetails: PhoneNumberDetails?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case address
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.address = try? container.decode(Address.self, forKey: .address)

        // ["email": Value] -> static key => Email Swift Object
        // ["email": Value] -> only object => email.emailContent. Here Value has only one object.
        self.email = try decoder.decodeStaticTitledElement(with: TitleKey(stringValue: "email")!, Email.self)

        // ["phone_numbers": Value] -> static key => PhoneNumberDetails Swift Object
        // ["phone_numbers": Value] -> multiple objects => phoneNumberDetails.phoneNumbers. Here Value has multiples objects.
        self.phoneNumberDetails = try decoder.decodeStaticTitledElement(with: TitleKey(stringValue: "phone_numbers")!, PhoneNumberDetails.self)
    }
}

struct Address: Decodable {
    let city: String
    let country: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case city
        case country
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.city = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
        self.country = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)
    }
}

/*
 * Extends SingleTitleDecodable.
 * Object that was mapped to static key "email".
 * SingleTitleDecodable uses when you know the Parent object has only one dynamic key-value pair
 * In this case Parent object is "email" object in the json, and "example@gmail.com": { body } is the only dynamic key-value pair
 * key-value pair is mapped into EmailContent
 */
struct Email: SingleTitleDecodable {
    let emailContent: EmailContent?

    init(title: String, element: EmailContent?) {
        self.emailContent = element
    }
}

struct EmailContent: Decodable {
    let emailAddress: String
    let verified: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case verified
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.emailAddress = try decoder.currentTitle()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.verified = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .verified)
    }
}

/*
 * Extends TitleDecodable.
 * Object that was mapped to static key "phone_numbers".
 * TitleDecodable uses when you know the Parent object has multiple dynamic key-value pair
 * In this case Parent object is "phone_numbers" object in the json, and "+94772222222": { body }, "+94772222222": { body } are the multiple dynamic key-value pairs
 * Multiple dynamic key-value pair are mapped into PhoneNumber array
 */
struct PhoneNumberDetails: TitleDecodable {
    let phoneNumbers: [PhoneNumber]

    init(title: String, elements: [PhoneNumber]) {
        self.phoneNumbers = elements
    }
}

struct PhoneNumber: Decodable {
    let number: String
    let isActive: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isActive
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.number = try decoder.currentTitle()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.isActive = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isActive)
    }
}
```

Focus on how the Json has transformed into the Object structure. Here is the mechanism extracted and improved from Rob's answer.

```
import Foundation

/*
 * This is to handle unknown keys.
 * Convert Keys with any String value to CodingKeys
 */
struct TitleKey: CodingKey {
    let stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}

extension Decoder {

    /*
     * Decode map into object array that is type of Element
     * [Key: Element] -> [Element]
     * This will be used when the keys are dynamic and have multiple keys
     * Within type Element we can embed relevant Key using => 'try decoder.currentTitle()'
     * So you can access Key using => 'element.key'
     */
    func decodeMultipleDynamicTitledElements<Element: Decodable>(_ type: Element.Type) throws -> [Element] {
        var decodables: [Element] = []
        let titles = try container(keyedBy: TitleKey.self)
        for title in titles.allKeys {
            if let element = try? titles.decode(Element.self, forKey: title) {
                decodables.append(element)
            }
        }
        return decodables
    }

    /*
     * Decode map into optional object that is type of Element
     * [Key: Element] -> Element?
     * This will be used when the keys are dynamic and when you're sure there'll be only one key-value pair
     * Within type Element we can embed relevant Key using => 'try decoder.currentTitle()'
     * So you can access Key using => 'element.key'
     */
    func decodeSingleDynamicTitledElement<Element: Decodable>(_ type: Element.Type) throws -> Element? {
        let titles = try container(keyedBy: TitleKey.self)
        for title in titles.allKeys {
            if let element = try? titles.decode(Element.self, forKey: title) {
                return element
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    /*
     * Decode map key-value pair into optional object that is type of Element
     * Key: Element -> Element?
     * This will be used when the root key is known, But the value is constructed with Maps where the keys can be Unknown
     */
    func decodeStaticTitledElement<Element: Decodable>(with key: TitleKey, _ type: Element.Type) throws -> Element? {
        let titles = try container(keyedBy: TitleKey.self)
        if let element = try? titles.decode(Element.self, forKey: key) {
            return element
        }
        return nil
    }

    /*
     * This will be used to know where the Element is in the Object tree
     * Returns the Key of the Element which was mapped to
     */
    func currentTitle() throws -> String {
        guard let titleKey = codingPath.last as? TitleKey else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Not in titled container"))
        }
        return titleKey.stringValue
    }
}

/*
 * Class that implements this Protocol, contains an array of Element Objects,
 * that will be mapped from a 'Key1: [Key2: Element]' type of map.
 * This will be used when the Key2 is dynamic and have multiple Key2 values
 * Key1 -> Key1: TitleDecodable
 * [Key2: Element] -> Key1_instance.elements
 * Key2 -> Key1_instance.elements[index].key2
 */
protocol TitleDecodable: Decodable {
    associatedtype Element: Decodable
    init(title: String, elements: [Element])
}
extension TitleDecodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init(title: try decoder.currentTitle(), elements: try decoder.decodeMultipleDynamicTitledElements(Element.self))
    }
}

/*
 * Class that implements this Protocol, contains a variable which is type of Element,
 * that will be mapped from a 'Key1: [Key2: Element]' type of map.
 * This will be used when the Keys2 is dynamic and have only one Key2-value pair
 * Key1 -> Key1: SingleTitleDecodable
 * [Key2: Element] -> Key1_instance.element
 * Key2 -> Key1_instance.element.key2
 */
protocol SingleTitleDecodable: Decodable {
    associatedtype Element: Decodable
    init(title: String, element: Element?)
}
extension SingleTitleDecodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init(title: try decoder.currentTitle(), element: try decoder.decodeSingleDynamicTitledElement(Element.self))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case we can't create static `codable` classes for this **JSON**.
Better use `JSON serialization` and retrive it.

Comment: You **can** create classes with `Codable` but you have to write custom initializers.