# JSON Parsing using Decodable protocol

Tags: json, swift, struct, decodable

I have json below for which I want to parse/assign values from

```
{
"Rooms":[
  {
     "id":"100",
     "title":"CS Classroom",
     "description":"Classroom for Computer science students",
     "capacity":"50"
  },
  {
     "id":"101",
     "title":"Mechanical Lab",
     "description":"Mechanical Lab work",
     "capacity":"50"
  },
  {
     "id":"108",
     "title":"Computer Lab",
     "description":"Computer Lab work",
     "capacity":"50"
  }
 ]
}
```

This json is of type [Dictionary: Dictonary] which has only key "Rooms"

While creating struct should I create

```
struct RoomsInfo: Decodable {
 let rooms: Rooms
}

struct Rooms {
  let id: String
  let title: String
  let description: String
  let capacity: String
}
```

My 1st Question is: Since I have only Rooms key , Is there a possiblity to create just one struct instead of two ?

My 2nd Question is: What if my json has keys as "Rooms1", "Rooms2", "Rooms3", "Rooms4"... in this case can i create structure which confirms to decodable or do i need to parse it manually?

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you have a key called `Room` so it has to decode that key,
is it possible to not have it sure, instead of parsing that `JSON` data first call out the value of that key `JSON["Rooms"]`, and parse what inside as a `[Room].self` ,

For the second question if the count is unlimited, as if you don't know how much `Room` key count are going to be, the `Decoder` abilities are limited then, however you can always map out the values as `Dictionary` and then decode the values as `Room` without caring about the key, this trick will do but you will abandon the original `Key`.

Update for the second case: 
Check out this code below.

```
typealias jsonDictionary = [String: Any]
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)! // converting test json string to data
var arrayOfRooms: [Room] = []
do {
let serialized = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) // serializing jsonData to json object
    if let objects = serialized as? [String: Any] { //casting to dictionary
        for key in objects.keys { //looping into the keys rooms (n) number
           let rooms = objects[key] // getting those rooms by key
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: rooms!, options: []) //converting those objects to data again to parse
            var myRoom = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Room].self, from: data) // decoding each array of rooms
            arrayOfRooms.append(contentsOf: myRoom) // appending rooms to main rooms array declared on top
        print("Data", data) // just to check
        }
        print("MY Array Of Rooms Count \(arrayOfRooms.count)")
    } else {
        print("nil")
    }

} catch {

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohmmad. I understood for 1st one.. like  let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Rooms.self, from: data[“Rooms”])   but for second one how can I omit key? because in .decode() function i need to pass from data..how can i pass that..can u pls let me know

Comment: do you need an example of the second one ?

Comment: this is where we have key with rooms1, 2, 3 .. an unknown number of keys

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1: Yes, it's possible with `nestedContainers` but the effort is greater than the benefit.

Answer #2: Decode the dictionary as `[String:Room]` or use custom  coding keys described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129682/use-swift-codable-to-decode-json-with-values-as-keys/54131007#54131007)