# How should I decode a json object using JSONDecoder if I am unsure of the keys

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable, jsondecoder

I have an api response in the following shape -

```
  {
   "textEntries":{
      "summary":{
         "id":"101e9136-efd9-469e-9848-132023d51fb1",
         "text":"some text",
         "locale":"en_GB"
      },
      "body":{
         "id":"3692b0ec-5b92-4ab1-bc25-7711499901c5",
         "text":"some other text",
         "locale":"en_GB"
      },
      "title":{
         "id":"45595d27-7e06-491e-890b-f50a5af1cdfe",
         "text":"some more text again",
         "locale":"en_GB"
      }
   }
}
```

I'd like to decode this via `JSONDecoder` so I can use the properties. The challenge I have is the keys, in this case `summary`,`body` and `title` are generated elsewhere and not always these values, **they are always unique**, but are based on logic that takes place elsewhere in the product, so another call for a different content article could return `leftBody` or `subTitle` etc.

The model for the body of these props is always the same however, I can expect the same fields to exist on any combination of responses.

I will need to be able to access the body of each key in code elsewhere. Another API response will tell me the key I need though.

I am not sure how I can handle this with `Decodable` as I cannot type the values ahead of time.

I had considered something like modelling the body -

```swift
struct ContentArticleTextEntries: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var text: String
    var locale: Locale
}
```

and storing the values in a struct like -

```swift
struct ContentArticle: Decodable {
    var textEntries: [String: ContentArticleTextEntries]


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case textEntries
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.textEntries = try values.decode(ContentArticleTextEntries.self, forKey: .textEntries)

    }

}
```

I could them maybe use a subscript elsewhere to access property however I do not know how to decode into this shape as the above would not work.

So I would later access like `textEntries["body"]` for example.

I also do no know if there is a better way to handle this.

I had considered converting the keys to a 'type' using an enum, but again not knowing the enum cases ahead of time makes this impossible.

**I know textEntries this does not change and I know id, text and locale this does not change. It is the keys in between this layer I do not know. I have tried the helpful solution posted by @vadian but cannot seem to make this work in the context of only needing 1 set of keys decoded.**

Comment: can u paste your complete json data

Comment: Sorry, I had missed off some braces, I have updated with the valid json response

Comment: What do you mean by ` match up the values on this response with the values from another response.`

Comment: Please ignore that, I may have confused my issue. I simply meant I need to access the property of `textEntries` using a key I can get from elsewhere. for example once I have these values, another response may require me to look up `body` etc

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129682/use-swift-codable-to-decode-json-with-values-as-keys/54131007#54131007, a pretty smart solution.

Comment: consider using nestedContainer:
```let nestedValues = try decoder.nestedContainer(keyedBy: NestedCodingKeys.self, forKey: .WhatEverYourKeyIs)```

Comment: Do you know the top level key? `textEntries`? This is always the same? Also the child elements are the same shape too? So in this case you do not know what the keys represented by `body` and `summary` etc will be?

Comment: Yes, I know `textEntries` this does not change and I know `id`, `text` and `locale` this does not change. It is the keys in between this layer I do not know. I have tried the helpful solution posted by @vadian but cannot seem to make this work in the context of only needing 1 set of keys decoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the proposed solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129682/use-swift-codable-to-decode-json-with-values-as-keys/54131007#54131007) the structs are

```
struct ContentArticleTextEntries: Decodable {
    let title : String
    let id: String
    let text: String
    let locale: Locale

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, text, locale
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.title = try decoder.currentTitle()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.text = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        let localeIdentifier = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .locale)
        self.locale = Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier)
    }
}     

struct ContentArticle: TitleDecodable {
    let title : String
    var elements: [ContentArticleTextEntries]
}

struct Container: Decodable {
    let containers: [ContentArticle]
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.containers = try decoder.decodeTitledElements(ContentArticle.self)
    }
}
```

Then decode `Container.self`

Comment: Thank you , that is a massive help, this is producing an array of `[textEntries]` - is it possible for `textEntries` to be a single prop with an array of `ContentArticleTextEntries` as it's value? I really really appreciate your help with this. Any pointers on how to amend this would help me greatly.

Comment: You should amend `Container` to `let containers: [ContentArticleTextEntries]` instead I believe

Comment: You get the array of `ContentArticleTextEntries` with `containers.first!.elements`

Comment: Thank you, so so much. I have no words, thank you. I have learned a lot from this.

Comment: Still saving lives! 

Answer (score 0):

Use "decodeIfPresent" variant method instead of decode method also you need to breakdown the ContentArticleTextEntries dictionary into individual keys:

```
struct ContentArticle: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var text: String?
    var locale: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, text, locale
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id) ?? ""
        self.text = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .text)
        self.locale = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .locale) 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your models are like,

```
struct ContentArticle: Decodable {
    let textEntries: [String: ContentArticleTextEntries]
}

struct ContentArticleTextEntries: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var text: String
    var locale: String
}
```

Then, you can simply access the data based on `key` like,

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ContentArticle.self, from: data)
let key = "summary"
print(response.textEntries[key])
```

**Note:** No need to write `enum CodingKeys` and `init(from:)` if there is no special handling while parsing the JSON.

Comment: How do I take the JSON response and create `[String: ContentArticleTextEntries]`? `ContentArticleTextEntries` is the body of each field, I would need the key of each field to be added my dict?

Comment: You must be getting the `data` as response right? I've added how you can parse that data. In the above code, `response` is of type `[String: ContentArticleTextEntries]`.

Comment: Ni I'm afraid not,  vadian posted a comment further up that pointed to a solution, but I have been unable to make that work in this case. The trouble I am having is that I do no know the keys I am trying to decode, in my example for instance `summary` and `body` could be anything, however their props `ContentArticleTextEntries` will always be that shape. Any help would be awesome please.