# How to decode JSON dictionary (with varying keys) of dictionaries, using Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, codable

I have the following simple JSON:

```
{
    "201" :
    {
        "countryName" : "Albania",
        "countryCode" : "AL"
    },
    "202" :
    {
        "countryName" : "Andorra",
        "countryCode" : "AD"
    },
    ...
}
```

The inner dictionary simply becomes:

```
struct Mid : Codable
{
    var countryName: String
    var countryCode: String
}
```

But then I'm stuck.  How do I represent the outer dictionary?

I want to end up with a dictionary of `Mid` objects with `String` keys `"201"`, `"202"`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Simple solution:

  - Decode `[String:Mid]`
- Sophisticated solution if you want an array:

  - [This great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129682/use-swift-codable-to-decode-json-with-values-as-keys/54131007#54131007) by Rob Napier